# Syntax error Python

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and trying to get the following simple program to run. Getting a syntax error after the colon in the first if clause.

Could someone tell me why and how to fix it and rest of program.

Tried many different things, nothing works.

Thank you!!!

```
# calculate salary

yearly = rate * 40 * 52
weekly1 = rate * 40
weekly2 = rate / 52
hourly = (rate / 52) / 40


print "Welcome to Salary Calculator"
calc = raw_input ("Convert hourly (h) or yearly (y) wage? "


# yearly wage
if calc == "y":
    raw_input ("Hourly wage: ") % rate  
    print "Weekly wage: " % weekly1
    print "Yearly wage: " % yearly

# hourly wage
elif calc == "h":
    raw_input("Yearly wage: ") % rate
    print "Weekly wage: " % weekly2
    print "Hourly wage: " % hourly


else:
    print "That is not a valid response, try again."
```

return

Answer (score 6):

You forgot a closing parenthesis:

```
calc = raw_input ("Convert hourly (h) or yearly (y) wage? "
                                                 -----------^
```

When in doubt, look to the previous line for unbalanced closing parens or brackets.

Comment: @larsmans: poko, poko, on the case already. :-)